# Making a connection with Socket.connect using timeout

Tags: java, sockets, connection, timeout

I'm making a java TCP connection using the Socket class.

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host,port),50);
```

I want this connection to be established fast or not being established at all, so I'm using 50 ms for the connection timeout.

But if I measure the time in-between those calls, I get more than 50 ms: 125ms, even 200ms. To measure the time I'm using System.currentMillis(). I know the granularity of this method it's not very good, but +100ms discrepancy is just ridiculous.

There is a problem with the connect method? It's 50 ms too little time for the timeout? I'm using java 1.7.0_03 with windows 7.

Comment: I am not sure if this is answerable without detailed knowledge of the implementation. It is also possible that the underlying OS uses a certain minimum value or granularity for the timeout value. Also take into account the time needed to resolve the IP-address from the hostname; this is not part of the connect timeout AFAIK.

Comment: Are you measuring successful or failed connects?

Comment: It is also possible that only first connect attempt takes long. Try to measure it in a loop of say, 100 connections.

Comment: 50ms is unreasonably short for a network timeout. Use a realistic value like a few seconds.

Comment: I'm measuring successful and failed connects, in a loop that has way more than 100 connections and the time taken is just inconsistent (62,55,67,251,104...). The host I'm using is in the format "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", so I don't think there's any ip-resolving involved. Strangely, the inconsistent timeout doesn't appear when I use hosts from my private network "192.168.1.x".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on tdn120's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779241/18573) I moved the `println` to finally. I get consistently <100. I too am running Windows 7, Java 7 (1.7.0).

```
javac -g SocketTest.java && java SocketTest localhost:80 abcd.com:80 localhost:80 localhost:80 localhost:80 
Testing: localhost:80
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
Time: 63
Testing: abcd.com:80
java.net.UnknownHostException: abcd.com
Time: 2350
Testing: localhost:80
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
Time: 50
Testing: localhost:80
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
Time: 50
Testing: localhost:80
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
Time: 50
```

My code is as follows:

```
import java.net.*;

public class SocketTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            args = new String[]{"localhost:80"};
        }
        for (String target: args) {
            test(target);
        }
    }

    private static void test(String target) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Testing: " + target);
        String[] parts = target.split(":");
        String host = parts[0];
        int port = Integer.valueOf(parts[1]);
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        long start = 0;
        try {
            start = System.nanoTime();
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), 50);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        } finally {
            long end = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println("Time: " + ((end - start) / 1000000));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but that's the thing I don't get. In your example, you get a 63 and a 2350. Why is that? I mean you are telling the method you don't want to wait more than 50 ms, so why it takes longer. Up to 2350! Maybe the timeout you pass to the connect method is just a sort of suggestion...

Comment: I was hoping you would notice the extra time. 50 ms is the socket connection timeout. When I use a name instead of i/p, especially an invalid name (abcd.com) the dns failure takes more time.

Comment: I was measuring the total time in the finally clause, after doing a socket.close() operation. It seems it takes a lot of time :(

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling it has to do with how you are timing it.  You need to make sure you are recording the times immediately before and after execution.

Although I am using Linux, I consistently get a result of 51 or 52 with this code:

```
public class SocketTest {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        long start = 0;
        try {
            start = System.nanoTime();
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.100", 80), 50);
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            long end = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println("Time: " + ((end - start) / 1000000));
        }
    }
}
```

Update: I tried it in Windows 7, I am getting 50's and 51's.

Comment: I'm measuring the time exactly as you do (but using currentMillis instead of nanoTime). Actually I get 50 and 51 when I use hosts from my private network, but not when I use external ips.